# Terminated App due to memory Pressure

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app to take images in Burst mode ,but once when the image is take and about to come the preview its getting crashed and error shows that **"Terminated App due to memory Pressure "**

I need to take more number of images when user holds the camera button...after Leave the button ,i need to show all the images as slideshow..what i have to do ?

My code is:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(takePictures)
                                                     name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
    }


-(void)takePictures
{
    [imagePicker takePicture];
}
```

Help me..

Answer (score 2):

Storing images in RAM is costly, due to the high resolution of the images. What more, your observer cause takePicture to be called multiple times - too many. As you take multiple pictures using the imagePicker, all these images quickly consume RAM, and since iOS has no swap - you run out of RAM.  Jetsam/memorystatus then kicks in, and kills your app, for having consumed so much memory.

Ways around this:

A) Take less pictures in burst mode. Use some global variable , say j, increment it in takePictures, but only take the actual picture on j % 2 == 0, or j %3 ==0 (you'll need to play around with the value)

B) try to save at least some of the photos to storage, then release them from RAM (remove the reference to them).

Comment: Thanks buddy..its really helpful.is it directly stored into RAM ?.then  i want to know how to release from RAM...?

Comment: Yaaa...I too want to know that process of releasing cached images from RAM