# Memory leakage due to the background task using GCD

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch

I am using the Method for background tasks as:

```
backgroundThumbnailQueue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async( backgroundThumbnailQueue, ^
                   { [self somemethod];
 dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   [self  Othermethod];

                               });
  });
```

Application is terminated by saying **Terminated due to the memory pressure**, but I don't know  where is the problem.

Can someone tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: Seem's your have a high quality image to thumbnail in `someMethod`,this could be cost too much RAM, and throw this error. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219263/terminated-app-due-to-memory-pressure?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Solved my problem, actually there was a memory allocation issue.